# What's meaning of BOS and EOS in CRFSuite feature list and what is the role of them?

Tags: python, text-mining, conditional-random-field, abbreviation

In NER(Named Entity Recognition) example in python-crf package website we see this function as feature generator:

```
def word2features(sent, i):
word = sent[i][0]
postag = sent[i][1]
features = [
    'bias',
    'word.lower=' + word.lower(),
    'word[-3:]=' + word[-3:],
    'word[-2:]=' + word[-2:],
    'word.isupper=%s' % word.isupper(),
    'word.istitle=%s' % word.istitle(),
    'word.isdigit=%s' % word.isdigit(),
    'postag=' + postag,
    'postag[:2]=' + postag[:2],
]
if i > 0:
    word1 = sent[i-1][0]
    postag1 = sent[i-1][1]
    features.extend([
        '-1:word.lower=' + word1.lower(),
        '-1:word.istitle=%s' % word1.istitle(),
        '-1:word.isupper=%s' % word1.isupper(),
        '-1:postag=' + postag1,
        '-1:postag[:2]=' + postag1[:2],
    ])
else:
    features.append('BOS')

if i < len(sent)-1:
    word1 = sent[i+1][0]
    postag1 = sent[i+1][1]
    features.extend([
        '+1:word.lower=' + word1.lower(),
        '+1:word.istitle=%s' % word1.istitle(),
        '+1:word.isupper=%s' % word1.isupper(),
        '+1:postag=' + postag1,
        '+1:postag[:2]=' + postag1[:2],
    ])
else:
    features.append('EOS')

return features
```

As you see after appending meaningful features - like **word.lower** and ...- two features has appended.

```
features.append('EOS')
```

and

```
features.append('BOS')
```

My question is "What's meaning of BOS and EOS and what is the role of them?"
You can see the completed tutorial there:
[python-crfsuite NER example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/tpeng/python-crfsuite/blob/master/examples/CoNLL%202002.ipynb#Features)

Comment: Could those stand for something like `Beginning Of Sentence` & `End Of Sentence`?

Comment: OK, I'll make that an official answer then.

Comment: Perhaps inspired by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the structure of the code, and my intuition, I would guess those stand for `Beginning Of Sentence` and `End Of Sentence`.  Specifically, `BOS` is only appended when `i == 0` (i.e., before anything else), and `EOS` is only appended when `i == len(sent)` (i.e., after everything else).